# Simulate keyboard press in different window

Tags: java, keyboard, window, communication, keyboard-events

I need to simulate keyboard button press in different window (media player to be specific).

I have the window name.

Is there a way to do that?

I'm sorry that i don't have anything to work with but i've been searching for anwswer for ages and still found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class.
An example is [here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-robot-class-example-mouse-keystroke) to find.

Comment: I'll try but i have some doubts about proper focus